# arch linux with nvidia Corporation TU117M can not start davince resolve with prime-run

Tags: linux, arch-linux, nvidia-graphics-card

I cannot start davince resolve application with prime-run command.

All dependencies were checked by `pacman | grep installed`.

I used `davinci-resolve-checker` to check the system. it passed to run the application.

How can I solve this problem and run the program?

davince check was passed:
[image: davince check was passed]

prime-run resolve:

[image: prime-run resolve]

prime-run gleax was successful:
[image: prime-run gleax was successful]